# A regular expression to match and exclude word/string

Tags: java, regex

I have strings like

```
patric NY abc other
patric ny
```

Expected output: `patric ny` and `patric NY`.

So, `patric ny` is varying statement which could be address. And `abc` MIGHT be there.

So, I want to retrieve random address like whatever we have before `ABC` 
and if `ABC` is not present , give the complete string.

I tried

```
(.+?(?=abc))
```

It gives me result for `patric NY abc other` but not for `patric ny`.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Do you want `^(.*?)(?:\s+abc\b.*)?$`? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/F6WCqA/2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Extracting approach**

You may use

```
^(.*?)(?:\s+abc\b.*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MZtR7E/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?:\s+abc\b.*)?` - an optional non-capturing group that matches 1+ whitespaces, `abc`, a word boundary and any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

**Replacing approach**

You may just remove 1+ whitespaces, `abc` and the rest from your string:

```
String result = input.replaceFirst("(?s)\\s+abc.*", "");
```

Or, if `abc` is a whole word:

```
String result = input.replaceFirst("(?s)\\s+abc\\b.*", "");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F6WCqA/1).

The `replaceFirst()` matches the first occurrence of the pattern and removes it.

**Pattern details**

- `(?s)` - DOTALL flag making `.` match any char
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `abc` - an `abc` substring
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `.*` - the rest of the string

Comment: thank you for reply!! Do not want to use in code, need it just as pattern , if we can have only regex

Comment: @AjinkyaBhogade Please explain what you are doing. To get the value, you will still need to use some code. Or tool.

Comment: @AjinkyaBhogade Do you want `^(.*?)(?:\s+abc\b.*)?$`? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/F6WCqA/2).

Comment: I have two string 1)patric NY abc 2)patric NY and i want to extract patric NY using pattern only .i used .+?(?=abc) this pattern but it works only when first string .it not works when i used second string

Comment: @AjinkyaBhogade Good. So, [this works for you, right?](https://regex101.com/r/MZtR7E/1)

Comment: @AjinkyaBhogade It **works**. Share regex fiddle, screenshot of your tool, post the code you are using in the question. Else, we can't help you.

Comment: ^(.*?)(?:\s+abc\b.*)?$  it works. Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

`intput.replaceFirst("(patric (?:NY|ny)) ((?:abc|ABC).*)","$1")`